# location.reload() and location.replace(url) not work in Electron with Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I use **Electron** to rebuild a ready web app. the electron **main.js** is simple:

```
    // Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1600, 
        height: 900
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('dist/mysite/index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

when i use **'electron .'** run the app, it works good except the line with **location**.
 The app code below is the login submit form action.
 After login there is one line **'location.reload()'** not work:

```
this.http.post(this.url + ':8000/' + 'auth/jwt/create/', this.validateForm.value)
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);

// This LINE NOT WORK 
location.reload();
// //////

    // this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);
    // this.router.navigate(['./']);
    console.log(location);
  }, (err: any) => {
    if (err.status === 400) {
      this.msg = err.error.non_field_errors[0];
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      this.msg = err;
      console.log(err);
    }
    this.isVisible = true;
  });
```

I try lots of ways to make the web go to the target url but failed.
**location.reload() location.replace router.navigate** all not work.
When I use 'ng serve' and open site with chrome, 'location.reload()' has no problem. So what should I do ? **Thank you.**

EDIT:
after location.reload() executed , the page go to blank. and when `console.log(location)`, the href is **chrome-error://chromewebdata/**

```
console.log(location)  
Location {replace: ƒ, assign: ƒ, href: "chrome-error://chromewebdata/", ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "null", …}
```

Comment: could you solve it? i'm trying to avoid win.reload and use windows.location.reload but it seems it does not work

Answer (score 3):

It stopped working for me when I introduced a Listener to my `browserView.webContents.on('will-navigate', ...);` and I was stopping some events, page reloading was blocked by that one.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you should use `window.location.reload()`, because `window` is a share object, and can access by anywhere such as `localStorage`.

```
window.location.reload()
```

You can also `console.log(location)` and `console.log(window.location)` to know the difference.

Comment: thank you. but window.location is the same as location. maybe this is a new feature in Angular 6. in console:  location === window.location
true

Comment: Have you try with `console.log(location)` and `console.log(window.location)`? (in Angular code, you can't access `location`, but it's OK with `window.location`)

Comment: In Angular, React and any framework, you should use `location` by `window.location`. Usually, packages on NPM which used both Node.JS and on browser, the browser version always use `window` as a share object without NPM usage

Comment: yes, i can use 'location' directly. **console.log(location)** output: **Location {replace: ƒ, assign: ƒ, href: "file:///home/hermit/frontend/mysite5/dist/mysite/host", ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "file://", …}**

Comment: Did you try this on Angular code? Because on console it always works.

Comment: i tried window.location.reload(),  the problem not solved.

Comment: Are you sure that line `localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);` working? On console what error shown when `location.reload();` run?

Comment: with angular window.location.reload() works fine but with electron it gives me a white screen.. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

So this has nothing to do with how you're calling window.location.reload(). By default, angular and other frameworks replace index.html with #/my-app-home-page. So the page loads correctly the first time, but if you try to reload the page, either programmatically or by using keyboard/menu, the page fails to load and you see the blank screen.

The fix is to ensure that /index.html stays in the url, which you can easily accomplish by changing the base tag:

```
<base href="./index.html" />
```